# Floating Submit Button

Tags: java, android

The submit button in the activity layout floats to the top left of the phone screen even after the fragment has been added resulting in it obscuring some of the fragment's content. should it not be pushed down when the following code is called:

currentFragment = MyFragment.newInstance();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.my_fragment, currentFragment).commit();

Activity Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.MyFragment"
              android:id="@+id/my_fragment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              tools:layout="@layout/my_fragment_layout"/>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/submit_button_text"
            />
</FrameLayout>
```

Fragment layout (my_fragment_layout.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/question_container"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/text"/>
    <RadioGroup android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radio_buttons"></RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

What am I missing about fragments and layouts here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement , your `Activity` parent layout should be `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` not `FrameLayout`. Also set a layout weight for `Fragment` layout, so that it will occupy the remaining space, used by the `Button`

Change your activity layout like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <fragment 
    android:id="@+id/my_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/my_fragment_layout"
    android:layout_weight="100"/>
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/submit_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="submit_button_text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

One more suggestion here. If your adding your `Fragment` using `Fragment Manager` programmatically  you can just define the `Fragment` container as `FrameLayout` in XML (Any way your creating the instance of fragment in code).

```
 <FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/my_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="100"/>
```

Hope this helps to fix your issue.